# Does the spectrum of two-beam interference also show an interference pattern?

Tags: optics, interference, spectroscopy, interferometry

I know when you interfere two beams you get an interference pattern with a fringe pattern of λ/(2*sin(θ/2)) in physical space.  It seems that there must also be modulation of the spectrum.  Is this true, and if so, how do you calculate what it looks like?

As a follow-up if there is spectral interference fringes to observe, would the spectral modulation be observable at any location in the physical pattern, or would it present itself as a change in wavelength across the interference pattern?  Practically, would you want to collect a large amount of the physically overlapped beam and send it through a spectrometer to observe the pattern in the spectrum, or perhaps a small probe that would scan across the pattern in physical space?

Thank you!

Comment: [Double-slit with sunlight](https://youtu.be/Iuv6hY6zsd0?t=216) by Veritaseum. The timestamped link goes to an image of the interference pattern which shows the kind of spectral modulation that I think you're asking about, but the whole video is useful.

Answer (score 2):

With monochromatic illumination of a double-slit interferometer, there is no spectral modulation. The resulting fringe pattern is monochromatic.

With white light illumination, the resulting fringe pattern is a superposition of monochromatic fringe patterns, each with fringe spacing that corresponds to its wavelength.  So, the resulting fringe pattern has a mixture of wavelengths whose relative intensity varies along the pattern.